# How to create a matrix of function handles in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to create a matrix of function handles or actually any method that can solve my following specific problems.

I first have a matrix `Utheta = [exp(1j*theta/2) 0;0 exp(-1j*theta/2)]` where `theta` is a parameter that I will do the integral w.r.t. it. Then I want to build a new matrix based on this one with `UthetaN = kron(Utheta,Utheta);` (this is a simplified version, actually the matrix is built from kron a lot of times). Then I want to do the integral of `UthetaN` w.r.t. `theta`. However, if I declare theta as a symbol using `syms theta real`, it will be very slow, I want to use `integral` method in Matlab which will be quicker. Hence I tried `Utheta = @(theta) [exp(1j*theta/2) 0;0 exp(-1j*theta/2)]` but an error happens when I execute `UthetaN = kron(Utheta,Utheta)`.

Comment: What do you mean by integrating the matrix? Typically you’d integrate component-wise, so you’d compute the. Integral of `exp(1j*theta/2)` and the other comportments, then you form your larger matrix using `kron` with the results of the integration.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your comment. Yes, I do integral component-wise. But I want to first do the kron and then integrate component-wise instead of first integrating component-wise and then doing the kron. The results are different.